# How to coil or wrap

Tags: animation

Im making an audio cassette and i want to coil or wrap the roll from end to another. At one end it should increase and other it should decrease. How can i animate that. A reference image is attached[image]

Comment: one way could be to animate the scale and rotation of two black circles... it depends on how much realistc its hould be...

Comment: can u plz explain in brief with small example so that i can understand clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expand the comment above: here is a rough example:

I created a "tape" black circle which will be animated (rotated and scaled). Then I put another object just over it, to represent the cassette gear, which has a copy rotation constraint to the tape.

here it is:

[image]

and

[image]

Then I animated it over 60 frames, putting 4 "rotscale" keyframes.

Here you see them, and you see the "tape" at frame 1

[image]

if you press ALT+A the tape and gear rotate, and "tape disk" becomes smaller...

..and after 60 frames, at 4th keyframe, you get:

[image]

Of course you could get much more realistic results, but this is just a fast example to get an inspiration...

**update**

here is the .blend I intended to append before

[image]

in which, as a bonus, I added a "complete" (simplified) cassette setup:

[image]

I used two empties to move the "tape" mesh ends, following the scaled tape gears...  see the .blend for more details.

Comment: thanks for the brief explanation. but what about the coil from one end to other . i will try

Comment: oops. the .blend link is missing...?!? sorry I have that at home, I'll pu tit into the post later... of course you should aniamte two different gears, on escaling up while the other down, and add a "tape" mesh attached to each, probably a a vertex parent, or so... I'll try later, too.

Comment: see the updated answer, I added a "complete" example... and the blend, this time! :D

Comment: thanks for the file and great animation i hope i can learn much more from u good experts